# Join trazendo valor errado

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho duas tabelas

Empresa:

```
id_empresa   id_usuario   vl_honorario   dt_honorario   id_honorario
   86             1            200       2017-01-04           7
   86             1            600       2016-12-01           6
   86             1            500       2016-11-01           5
   86            212           300       2016-12-01           5
```

Honorario:

```
id_honorario   tp_honorario  
   5             Mensal                 
   6             Anual
   7             Trimestral
```

Estou tentando agrupar o Valor do Honorário `vl_honorario` se a data do honorário for igual ao mês 12 ou se o Tipo do Honorário `tp_honorario` = 'Mensal'.
A sql está assim:

```
SELECT SUM(h.vl_honorario) as vl_honorario, h.id_usuario 
FROM empresa as h 
INNER JOIN honorario as p ON p.tp_honorario = 'Mensal' 
WHERE h.id_empresa = 86 
AND MONTH(h.dt_honorario) = 12 
GROUP by h.id_usuario
```

E me retorna:

```
vl_honorario   id_usuario  
   600             1                 
   300            212
```

Mas deveria me retornar o resultado abaixo, pois em 2016-11-01 tenho o valor de 500, que deveria estar sendo considerado pois o tipo do honorário é Mensal

```
vl_honorario  id_usuario  
    1100          1                 
    300          212
```

Comment: O honorário mensal é somado independente de qualquer vínculo, isso?

Comment: @Sorack isso mesmo.

Comment: Seu problema é o AND MONTH(h.dt_honorario) = 12 , você só tem 2 meses com esse valor

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza é porque preciso verificar se o MONTH(h.dt_honorario) = 12 e se o tp_honorario = Mensal

Comment: Na realidade a sua `query` está com alguns erros. Seu `INNER JOIN` não tem vínculo nenhum e ele limitaria o número de resultados. Vou tentar corrigi-la

Comment: Para começo seu join esta errado a relação seria on p.id_honorario= p.id_honorario e no seu where p.tp_honorario = 'Mensal'  ...

Comment: Exatamente. Tá na resposta lá como ficaria sua `query`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está utilizando erroneamente o `INNER JOIN`, fazendo o vínculo pelo que deveria ser sua condição `OR`:

```
SELECT SUM(h.vl_honorario) as vl_honorario,
       h.id_usuario
  FROM empresa as h
       INNER JOIN honorario as p ON p.id_honorario = h.id_honorario
 WHERE h.id_empresa = 86
   AND (MONTH(h.dt_honorario) = 12
    OR p.tp_honorario = 'Mensal')
 GROUP by h.id_usuario
```

Answer (score 1):

Existe dois ponto que você precisar se atentar. Sua relação entre as tabelas `ON p.id_honorario = h.id_honorario`, deixe o filtro para a clausular `and p.tp_honorario = 'Mensal'` , outra coisa quando você faz  `AND MONTH(h.dt_honorario) = 12`  você retorna todos os meses que são iguais a 12, e na sua amostra só existem 2 meses, então sua soma não terá mais do que o primeiro resultado que você demostrou.

```
SELECT SUM(h.vl_honorario) as vl_honorario, h.id_usuario 
FROM empresa as h 
INNER JOIN honorario as p 

-- sua relação
ON p.id_honorario = h.id_honorario

WHERE h.id_empresa = 86 
-- isso aqui filtra todos os meses = 12
-- ou seja só tem 2 meses como você mostrou na pergunta
AND MONTH(h.dt_honorario) = 12 
and p.tp_honorario = 'Mensal' 
GROUP by h.id_usuario
```

Para fazer o que você descreveu;

> Estou tentando agrupar o Valor do Honorário vl_honorario se a data do
>   honorário for igual ao mês 12 ou se o Tipo do Honorário tp_honorario =
>   'Mensal'. A sql está assim:

É necessário que seu filtro `p.tp_honorario = 'Mensal'` seja usando como um `OR`. Ou seja,

```
  AND (MONTH(h.dt_honorario) = 12 or p.tp_honorario = 'Mensal')
```